# Vuejs when reseting data TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to empty my data varaibles back to the original state, like so:

```
export default
{
    data: function () 
    {
        return {
            countries: [],
            name: '',
            summary: '',
            salarytype: '',
            salaryfrom: '',
            salaryto: '',
            location: '',
            contactemail: '',
            contactphone: '',
            errors: new Errors()
        }
    },

    methods: 
    {
        addJob: function()
        {
            axios.post('/jobs/create', this.$data)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.data.status === true){
                    resetFields();
                    $('#createJob').modal('hide');
                    getJobTable();
                }
                else{
                    formError = response.data.message;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.data))
        },
        resetFields: function() {
            Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));
        }
    },

    mounted: function()
    {
        axios.get('/countries')
            .then(response => {
                this.countries = response.data;
            })
    }
}
```

When doing that I get an error saying:

```
app.js:34533 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Errors.get (app.js:12209)
    at Proxy.render (app.js:33512)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:36314)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:36707)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:37032)
    at Watcher.run (app.js:37101)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js:36905)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:34571)
    at nextTickHandler (app.js:34520)
    at <anonymous>
```

I have checked stack for resetting the data values, and it recomends doing it the way I am above, but that is throwing the error. How can I fix this so I can reset my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(response.data.status === true){
  resetFields();
```

that should probably be

```
 if(response.data.status === true){
  this.resetFields();
```

If you want to run the component method by that name.

Do you also have a function by that name defined outside of the component definition? or is this a typo in your example?

Comment: Adding this.resetFields() worked. Thank you very much, sir